# How to sort objects in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I am having a hard time to find proper syntax of list.sort command to pick up correct highest value from array. I have following list of objects:

```py
[((6, (192, 96, 128)), 1), ((49, (128, 32, 64)), 1), ((2, (128, 96, 0)), 1),
 ((4, (160, 160, 160)), 1), ((41977, (64, 160, 160)), 1), ((1787, (128, 32, 128)), 1),
 ((8, (128, 96, 160)), 1), ((1, (192, 96, 160)), 1), ((14381, (0, 0, 32)), 1),
 ((2, (64, 96, 64)), 1), ((9, (192, 128, 160)), 1), ((410, (64, 32, 64)), 1),
 ((75, (192, 160, 96)), 1), ((6, (96, 0, 32)), 1), ((142163, (0, 160, 128)), 1),
 ((2468, (224, 192, 64)), 1), ((95, (64, 0, 32)), 1), ((224, (0, 128, 160)), 1),
 ((57, (96, 32, 32)), 1), ((40, (160, 96, 64)), 1)]
```

and I would like to sort it so I pick up the highest value: `((142163, (0, 160, 128)), 1)`

Can someone please help me to construct a command that either sorts the list in descending order, or picks up the max() value of 142163 and returns its associated element (0,160,128)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: try `print(sorted(x)[-1])`

Answer (score 4):

in your case, you don't need to sort (`O(log(n)*n)` complexity) since you only need one value. The fastest is just to use `max` (`O(n)` complexity) as the order of your structures follows the natural order

```
>>> max(x)
((142163, (0, 160, 128)), 1)
```

`max` also accepts a `key` argument for more complex sorting cases.

Answer (score 3):

- you can pass key in `sorted` function of python. You can also use `sort` function which is inplace function.

```py
lst = [((6, (192, 96, 128)), 1), ((49, (128, 32, 64)), 1), ((2, (128, 96, 0)), 1), ((4, (160, 160, 160)), 1), ((41977, (64, 160, 160)), 1), ((1787, (128, 32, 128)), 1), ((8, (128, 96, 160)), 1), ((1, (192, 96, 160)), 1), ((14381, (0, 0, 32)), 1), ((2, (64, 96, 64)), 1), ((9, (192, 128, 160)), 1), ((410, (64, 32, 64)), 1), ((75, (192, 160, 96)), 1), ((6, (96, 0, 32)), 1), ((142163, (0, 160, 128)), 1), ((2468, (224, 192, 64)), 1), ((95, (64, 0, 32)), 1), ((224, (0, 128, 160)), 1), ((57, (96, 32, 32)), 1), ((40, (160, 96, 64)), 1)]
lst = sorted(lst, key = lambda x:x[0][0], reverse=True) # sort by first element of first tuple of each object. reverse=True will give you decending order
print(lst[0])
print(lst[0][0][1])
```

- output

```
((142163, (0, 160, 128)), 1)
(0, 160, 128)
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I know but the point is to give OP idea of `key` parameter of sorted function for future reference. Explicit is better than implicit. (Reference https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)